# Is it possible to move newer commit behind older one?

Tags: git

Say I have following git history:

```
commit C # Most recent one 
commit B
commit A # First one
```

And I want to rearrange the `C` commit to be the second one making the `B` commit the first as follow:

```
commit B # Being now the latest
commit C # Previously the latest, now second in history
commit A # Still the first
```

Btw I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080443/how-can-i-reorder-combine-commits-using-git-rebase) to be a possible duplicate, but the question is too complicated for my simple use case as I don't mess commits with branches.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: It is quite regular to split your code modifications into separate commits so that the changes are more comprehensible. And I've made some changes that would make much more sense during the code review in case of rearranged commits instead of the current sequence, when the reviewer follows up my proposed changes - commit by commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rebase`

```
git rebase -i A
```

Then change the order from

```
commit C
commit B
```

change to

```
commit B
commit C
```

and continue the `rebase`.

Comment: Huh, I haven't even thought it could be that easy :) thanks!