# Using git rebase, how to squash a commit into a non-previous commit

Tags: git, github, git-rebase, git-squash

I know that using `git rebase -i`, I could squash a commit which will meld the commit message into the immediate previous commit.

https://github.com/wprig/wprig/wiki/How-to-squash-commits

But using `git rebase -i`, is it possible to squash a commit into not the previous commit but a commit even older? Lets say I want to squash a commit with a commit that is 3 commits prior to the commit being squashed. If yes, then how?

Comment: See [Cascabel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2740812/1256452) in particular, in the first linked duplicate. See [Wayne Conrad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2080543/1256452) in the second.

Comment: Yeah. I got the answer here as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921708/how-do-i-squash-two-non-consecutive-commits.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I've added that to the collection. Your question has both keywords "squash" and "rebase", which a lot of these don't.

Comment: @torek Great! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you use `git rebase -i` you are able to reorder the commit if you want to a new order.

If you e.g. do `git rebase -i HEAD~5` and end with this:

```
  pick bfddbf6 first  commit
  pick 74b19b1 second commit
  pick 03892e7 third  commit
> pick 0fdc12c fourth commit
  pick 9e422a0 fifth  commit
```

you can reorder the fifth commit as second to squash it into the first:

```
  pick bfddbf6 first  commit
> squash 0fdc12c fourth commit
  pick 74b19b1 second commit
  pick 03892e7 third  commit
  pick 9e422a0 fifth  commit
```